# Should we make @babel/runtime external when using rollup and babel to develop a react component lib?

Tags: rollup

In the rollup-plugin-babel doc(https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/babel), it says that we should set `babelHelpers` to `runtime` when building libraries with Rollup:

> It has to be used in combination with @babel/plugin-transform-runtime and you should also specify @babel/runtime as dependency of your package.

That's ok and i understand it.

But i can't understand the following line:

> **Don't forget to tell Rollup to treat the helpers imported from within the @babel/runtime module as external dependencies when bundling for cjs & es formats**

Why? As i know, the user of my lib should provide the `@babel/runtime` package if i make it external. But the user may not use it. It is NOT as common as `react`, etc.

Comment: Am asking myself the same, tho, `@babel/runtime` should be installed as a dependency, not dev dependency solving the second problem. What I'm struggling is, why use `runtime` over `bundled`.